# Comment notification not working

Tags: comments, email, notifications

I use a different theme named Team Talk (Premium). Since I use this theme, I don't receive the new comment notification by email.
I don't know where to look at but I found this in my new theme :

```
function get_content_html_for_comment($comment){
    $comment_html  = "";
    // Get the comment data
    //switch on the output buffer
    ob_start();
    // Allow the email to the author to be sent
    wp_notify_postauthor($comment_ID, $comment->comment_type);
    $max_depth = get_option('thread_comments_depth');
    $args = array ('max_depth' => $max_depth);
    //render the content to the output buffer
    //call _ht_comment 
    echo _ht_comment($comment, $args, $this->calculate_comment_depth($comment));
    //the content will now be in the buffer, so get that
    $comment_html = ob_get_contents();
    //restore buffer
    ob_end_clean();
    return $comment_html;
```

So, it seems to allow to receive notification but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you contacted the theme author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see the `$comment_ID` variable having any value in your code. So try by changing the following code

```
wp_notify_postauthor($comment_ID, $comment->comment_type);
```

to

```
wp_notify_postauthor($comment->comment_ID, $comment->comment_type);
```

You can also remove `$comment->comment_type` as per **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_notify_postauthor)**

Comment: You are my hero